# Android can not find com.microsoft.device.display:display-mask:0.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone have a thought as to why code that I have not compiled in over a year, on Android Studio is now giving me this on my compile?  I don't[image] know where I would even use device.display from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding the following dependency to the project parent build.gradle. I had it in a module build.gradle and got the same error as you.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MicrosoftDeviceSDK/DuoSDK-Public/_packaging/Duo-SDK-Feed/maven/v1'
        }
    }
}
```